# Matching a string with a wildcard and at least two preceeding characters

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to create a regex that accepts:

- Alphabetic (upper or lowercase)
- full stops, commas, hyphens, apostrophes and spaces
- If using a wildcard, it must be preceded by at least two of the aformentioned characters
- The string must be a minimum of one character (if not using wildcard) and 30 characters in length.

I've constructed this regex but it's not currently working as desired:

`/^(?:[A-Za-z.,'\\-\\s]|[^%]%(?:.{2,}|)) {1,30}$/`

Do you have any suggestions on how to refine this to meet desired behaviour? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

These are valid matches:

`asdSRVGD`
`as%`
`assvd-,'`
`asdbSERF,%`

Comment: Could you give some input examples?

Comment: So `%` is the wildcard?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) the question to add examples (and counter-examples). *Don't* put them here in the comment section.

Comment: @InSync Question edited to include valid matches.

Comment: @isaactfa yes, that's correct

Comment: Does "*two of the aformentioned characters*" mean only `a-z`, or `.,-' ` as well (e.g. `. %` is valid)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct @InSync

Comment: You have a space before the quantifier! That means 1 to 30 SPACES.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand the requirements correctly, but it seems that you want something like this:

```
(?i)                     # Match case-insensitively
^                        # at the beginning
(?=.{1,30}$)             # a string whose length is >= 1 and <= 30
(?:                      # which contains either
  [a-z.,'\-\h]{2}%       # two of the permitted characters followed by a percent sign
|                        # or
  [a-z.,'\-\h]           # a single one of those
)+                       # 1 or more times
$                        # right before the end.
```

This is in PCRE, but it should be easy to transpile it into other flavors of regex, including those which doesn't support lookarounds (by checking the length separately).

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ul6IH6/1).

Answer (score 1):

The examples seem to have a single optional wildcard.

If a lookahead is supported (note that `\s` can also match a newline):

```
^(?=.{1,30}$)[a-zA-Z.,'\s-]*(?:[a-zA-Z.,'\s-]{2}%[a-z.,'\s-]*)?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^(?=.{1,30}$)` Assert 1-30 char from the start till end of string
- `[a-zA-Z.,'\s-]*` Optionally repeat matching any of the listed chars
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[a-zA-Z.,'\s-]{2}%` Match 2 times any of the listed and then `5~
  - `[a-z.,'\s-]*` Optionally repeat matching any of the listed chars
- `)?` Close the group and make it optional
- `$`  End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N5MzJa/1) (using a space instead of `\s`)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://regex101.com/r/h4UErp/1) matches all your examples:

```
^([A-Za-z.,' -]{1,30}|[A-Za-z.,' -]{2}[A-Za-z.,' %-]{1,28})$
```

It matches either up to 30 non-`%` characters or two non-`%` characters followed by up to 28 arbitrary characters, where characters are from the set `A-Za-z.,' %-`.